# Monitoring Windows Server 2008 usage using nsclient++

Tags: windows-server-2008, nagios, nsclient++

I'm setting up a monitoring system for our servers. I installed nagios on a linux box and then I installed nsclient++ (with these instruction http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/monitoring-windows.html) (windows server 2008 r2). I thought it was easy but nsclient++ doesn't communicate with my nagios box. All services are down. Nsclient'log is this but I can't figure out what's wrong. 
[image]

Launching nsclient from the console doesn't give me any error so it seems it ok.

UPDATE:
I found 1 error due to Rackspace networking and the firewall. Now if I run manually

> /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nt -H
>   IP -p 12489 -v UPTIME

it works fine, I set the same IP used here in the windows.cfg config file but in Nagios everything is still not working

Have you any idea?

Comment: You can make sure that nsclient is listening and waiting for requests. Use `netstat -anb`.

Comment: @Khaled Yes it's listening, but on my remote linux I don't see it open. I'm now with rackspace support to understand why

Comment: Ok port is open, firewall is down. Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the command works fine from command line check commands.cfg at nagios server for the check_nt UPTIME service and replicate it to your service command:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_nt_uptime
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nt -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 12489 -v UPTIME
    }
```

--

```
define service{
    use                             windows.template
    host_name                       hostname
    service_description             Uptime
    check_command                   check_nt_uptime
    }
```

Regards.

Comment: It works!!! I copied the windows.cfg and commands.cfg from the debian templates, I suppose they are broken with my config!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the "Log viewer". Id recomend running nsclient++ in "/test mode" as that will also enable debug log.

So try the following:

```
nsclient++ /stop
nsclient++ /test
...
... (run commands from nagios, ans see where what happens...)
...
exit
nsclient++ /start
```

In most cases though this is related to the built-in firewall which many people forget to configure.

Comment: See the update on my question I got some news